# Phonegap; Does the developer app support 3rd party plugins?

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, adobe, command-line-interface

I'm trying to add the 3rd party plugin; BarcodeScanner to my project and have done successfully. When building the final app it works fine.

**However is there any way to add this plugin to allow the iOS 'PhoneGap' app without having to build the project?**

I've tried CLI to add the plugin and also have added the plugin to my config.xml; I've also looked on google and cannot find an answer. Some people say you can and others say you can't.

Thanks

*bump*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap App is essentially a cordova app with a fixed set of plugins installed. The app is capable of downloading and executing the css/html/javascript parts of a Cordova application. However, It is not possible to install a plugin that includes native parts over-the-air.